# Curl POST command into a bat file

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have the following batch file that is executing cURL POST command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Hello:\"}"  https://xxx
exit
```

Then I exec the code with windows command, It's work. But if I tried with the same code on a bat file, It didn't work at all.
I thing it could be the "\" ?

Tks for your help.

Comment: It's not the `\"`, but probably your not shown URL contains percent signs. They have to be doubled in batch `http://ex.com/par1=%%25BLA`

Comment: Please show a real example of the URL, you can change the domain name if you feel you do not want to show it, but the key to the issue is in the URL.

Comment: Ok tks. Here the URL : mattermost.tech.xxx/hooks/iomqtasz5pn4bcuseqrwt317jc. I have no % or \ on it so maybe the "/" ? or the code before the domain ?

Comment: Anyone have a answer about it ? tks